# my articles dont display in my joomla template

Tags: joomla

I install TheGrue Menu module (joomla) my menu display but when I click on each item I will go to new page without articles! my articles dont display!

```
<div class="menu">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
             <div class="navbar-header menu">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="main-menu"/>
                   </div>
               </div>
         </nav>
   </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answers!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Click on your menu item then choose menu item type single article and select an article.
Select Target Window is Parent then Save and check your site. Hope this will help.